# C++ UDP server send message just when get client's address config

Tags: c++, sockets, udp

My purpose is to create a UDP sender to broadcast message to a specific IP and Port, without any config requirment. I defined `struct sockaddr_in si_me` variable to set the server config on it and bind it:

```
si_me.sin_family = AF_INET;
si_me.sin_port = htons(PORT);
si_me.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
if( bind(s , (struct sockaddr*)&si_me, sizeof(si_me) ) == -1)
    {
        die("bind");
    }
```

I expected when I send data to configured IP and Port in `si_me` variable, every client could receive the message but it doesn't happen and using both UDP client and `nc 127.0.0.1 9090 -u` command on Linux terminal, I couldn't receive any message!
I found that for each client I should create a `struct sockaddr_in si_other` variable. The client should send me a message so I can get client's config:

```
if ((recv_len = recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, (socklen_t*)&slen)) == -1)
        {
            die("recvfrom()");
        }
```

So now using `si_other` variable I can send messages successfully. I checked the `si_other` variable and I found the IP is the same with server IP but the Port is different for each client so because of this I couldn't send data to the client without knowing what is the destination Port!

Here is the complete source code:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in si_me, si_other;

    int s, i, slen = sizeof(si_other) , recv_len;
    char* msg = "Hellooooo\n";
    char buf[BUFLEN] ;

    //create a UDP socket
    if ((s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1)
    {
        die("socket");
    }

    // zero out the structure
    memset((char *) &si_me, 0, sizeof(si_me));

    si_me.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_me.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    si_me.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    std::cout << si_me.sin_addr.s_addr << std::endl ;
    std::cout << si_me.sin_port << std::endl ;
    std::cout << si_other.sin_addr.s_addr << std::endl ;
    std::cout << si_other.sin_port << std::endl ;
    if( bind(s , (struct sockaddr*)&si_me, sizeof(si_me) ) == -1)
        {
             die("bind");
        }

    // waiting to recieve client's message
    std::cout << "Waiting for start command ... " << std::endl ;
    if ((recv_len = recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, (socklen_t*)&slen)) == -1)
        {
            die("recvfrom()");
        }
    std::cout << si_me.sin_addr.s_addr << std::endl ;
    std::cout << si_me.sin_port << std::endl ;
    std::cout << si_other.sin_addr.s_addr << std::endl ;
    std::cout << si_other.sin_port << std::endl ;
    long count = 0 ;
    while(0)
    {

            if (sendto(s, msg, strlen(msg), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &si_other, slen) == -1)
            {
                die("sendto()");
            }
            std::cout << "Message number " << ++ count << " has been sent" << std::endl ;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

So can anyone tell me how should I change the source to broadcast messages without the need of getting client message to configure its destination IP and Port?

Comment: use the broadcast address for the current subnet: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to send a broadcast message, you must call `setsockopt` with level `SOL_SOCKET` and option name `SO_BROADCAST` (see `socket(7)` manual page). So, after creating the socket, (on the client side), you should have code like this:

```
int turn_on = 1;
retval = setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &turn_on, (socklen_t)sizeof(turn_on));
```

The sender can then specify a broadcast address in its send, and any station within the broadcast domain should be able to receive it. Any *server* would need to bind either to the broadcast address itself, or to `INADDR_ANY` in order to receive such a broadcast.

The way this typically works is:

- Server creates socket, and binds it to well known port with `INADDR_ANY`
- Client creates socket, does *not* bind it, but adds `SO_BROADCAST` option.
- Client calls `sendto` with buffer and `sockaddr_in` specifying a broadcast address and the well known port.
- Server calls `recvfrom` and receives datagram payload and client's address in return values
- Server calls `sendto` using the client address it obtained above (so it doesn't matter what port the client is using -- the server will know the client's port and IP address).
- Client calls `recvfrom` on same socket to receive reply messages from server

Typically there are two broadcast addresses available: one that is specific to the subnet (that's shown by `ifconfig`) -- something like 192.168.1.255 -- and the global broadcast address -- 255.255.255.255.

Listening on `INADDR_ANY` should allow you to receive datagrams sent to either broadcast address (or to a unicast address belonging to the server machine).

Answer (score 0):

There is no `bind()` call in the complete source code.
It is needed before `recvfrom()` call.

So add the bind() call to the source of server:

```
if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&si_me, sizeof(si_me)) == -1)
{
    die("bind");
}
```

If you are going to use the client and server in the same host, then you should bind different port to client than server.